# How to merge duplicate contacts in one contact which was created first by using batch apex

Tags: batch, merge

How can i merge duplicate contacts under original contact.
Orginal Contact : The contact which was created first is an original contact
And we have to merge all duplicate contact in that original contact

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_merge.htm). SOmething like this.

```
Contact master = [select id, firstname from contact where id = '123'];
List<Contact> duplicates = [select id from contact where firstname = master.firstname];
Database.MergeResult[] results = Database.merge(master, duplicates, false);
```

Comment: there are some limitations with the above -- `duplicates` can only be max size 2; your second query will fetch the original master record (it should avoid that in the filter; also needs bind variables); OP also asked for master being the earliest created Contact